# InsertBefore li element, Close button no show

Tags: javascript

I am making a TODO list, I want to add the items before the previous...
The code is working but for some reason, my Close Button is not coming..
But it is coming if I just add the items with "appendChild"

// Add list item

```
var list = document.createElement("li");
var textNode = document.createTextNode(textInput);
list.appendChild(textNode);
if (textNode == ' ') {
  alert("Nothing to add!");
} else {
  var uList = document.getElementById("my-todo-list").appendChild(list);
  // var uList = document.getElementById("my-todo-list");
  // uList.insertBefore(list, uList.childNodes[0]);
}
```

// Close Button

```
var listItems = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
  var spanItem = document.createElement('span');
  spanItem.style.float = 'right';
  var myCloseSymbol = document.createTextNode('\u00D7');
  spanItem.classList.add("closeBtn");
  spanItem.appendChild(myCloseSymbol);
  listItems[i].appendChild(spanItem);
}
```

[image: ![todo list](]

https://jsfiddle.net/headbangz/8yzdL312/

Comment: can you show your issue in fiddle or code snippet here?

Comment: I have placed a jsfiddle

Comment: In your fiddle, I can able to see the close button. what is the issue?

Comment: I forgot to uncomment the insertBefore

Comment: I think seems ok everything. All is fixed?

Comment: @ThomasHermansen I have found the issue and posted as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the issue on your code. The issue is there on the below code.

```
listItems[i].appendChild(spanItem);
```

As per your concept you are adding the new `li` element as first, but appending the close button on last `li` element. This statement should change like below.

```
listItems[0].appendChild(spanItem);
```

I have commented your insertBefore line and verify the same above. You can check it out in this updated [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/8yzdL312/2/).

Comment: Thanks... I had tried a lot of different stuff myself just couldnt see to find the solution...